# Differentiating a convergent power series with "missing terms"

Tags: calculus, power-series

Assume we have $$P(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k} x^{2k}$$

Also assume that it is convergent, even if it isn't. Just serves to illustrate the question. That is every $x$-term with an odd exponent is "missing". Can I still differentiate it like every other power series?

$$P'(x) = \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{2k}{k} x^{2k-1} = \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} 2 x^{2k-1} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 2 x^{2k+1}$$

Does it also still work if we "eliminate" a few $x$-terms by adding the following for an arbitrary $n \in \mathbb{N}$

$$P_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k} x^{2k+n}$$

Comment: Do you mean to start the index at $k=1$? It is undefined for $k=0$.

Comment: @JairTaylor Yes, this is an example that I came up on my own to illustrate my question. I will fix it.

Comment: Yes, if a power series is convergent, you can always differentiate term-by-term.

Comment: @JairTaylor So it is still a power series even if finitely many terms with $x$ are not present?

Comment: Note that the missing terms are still present   when writing them as $0\cdot x^j$. In your original question $a_j=\frac{2}{j} $ for even $j$ and $a_j=0$ if $j$ is odd.

Answer (score 1):

If you do the substitution $ u = x^2 $, you'll figure it's the same power series. Similarly for the other cases.

Also, you can always differentiate power series term-by-term, because both $f_n$ and $f'_n$ converge uniformly. [Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence#To_differentiability)

Answer (score 0):

Yes.By using Hadama formula,we know that the convergent radius of this series is $\rho$,such that $\frac{1}{\rho}=\varlimsup_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[\uproot{2} n]{a_n}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[\uproot{2} 2n]{\frac{1}{n}}=1$. And in the domain of convergence,we can differentiate term by term.

So you can focus on the radius of convergence and whether specific $x$ lies on that domain,but not care about what if some terms are “missing”.